# Zoom to fit algorithm

Tags: algorithm, lua, zooming

I'm trying to build a "zoom to fit" algorithm in Lua (Codea). Imagine a shape anywhere on Canvas. I would like to automatically zoom on the center of this shape so that it occupies most part of the Canvas and be centred on it. Finally, I would like to be able to zoom back out to the initial situation, so matrices should do the job. Is There a simple way to do this ? Any code, even not in Lua, is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C#,

```
double aspectRatio = shape.Width / shape.Height;

if (aspectRatio > 1)
{
    // Width defines the layout
    double origShapeWidth = shape.Width;
    shape.Width = panel.Width;
    shape.Height = panel.Width * shape.Height / origShapeWidth;

    // Center the shape
    double margin = (panel.Height - shape.Height) / 2;
    shape.Margin = new Thickness(0, margin, 0, margin);
}
else
{
    // Height defines the layout
    double origShapeHeight = shape.Height;
    shape.Height = panel.Height;
    shape.Width = panel.Height * shape.Width / origShapeHeight;

    // Center the shape
    double margin = (panel.Width - shape.Width) / 2;
    shape.Margin = new Thickness(margin, 0, margin, 0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll see that. Thank you again. Éric